# googletest: Testing for Data Structures That Are Too Large

Tags: c++, googletest

I've been trying to create a test case where my vectors are too large to be handled by my function, but my input validation does not get triggered when comparing the size of the input vector to std::vector

I'm using Bazel as my build platform and googletest as my test framework.

Here is the validation statement used to catch the oversize vector:

```
std::vector<int> Solution::fit_sum(std::vector<int> v, int sum)
{
  // input validation
  if(v.empty() || 
    v.size() > v.max_size() ||
    v.size() < 0) // handle int overflow
  {
    printf("input invalid\n");
    return {};
  }
  printf("v.size = %d\n", v.size());
  printf("v.max_size() = %d\n", v.max_size());

// functional code below
}
```

Here is the test case I created:

```
TEST(FIT_SUM_TEST, TOO_LARGE) {
  Solution solution;
  std::vector<int> input;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.max_size() + 1; i++)
  {
    input.push_back(i);
  }
  int sum = 1;
  std::vector<int> actual = solution.fit_sum(input, sum);
  std::vector<int> expected = {};
  EXPECT_EQ(expected, actual);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[ RUN      ] FIT_SUM_TEST.TOO_LARGE
v.size = -2147483648
v.max_size() = -1
[       OK ] FIT_SUM_TEST.TOO_LARGE (46174 ms)
```

I'm a bit confused because I'm not entering my input validation if statement even though the conditions are met.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit:

I realize that what I'm testing for is fundamentally flawed because any program building an array too large will crash.

I guess a better line of questioning is: 
1) How do I properly account for vectors that are too large? 
2) How do I determine just how large "too large" is?
3) The function itself has a runtime of O(n^2). Is there a different line of restrictions I should be putting on my input given this complexity?

Comment: what do you expect to get when you have a container that is full and you add one more element?

Comment: Side note: your sizes printing is broken too. Use `std::cout << v.size()` or proper specifier for `std::size_t`: `%z`

Comment: I really wonder how is this program not crashing. `max_size()` returns theoretical, non-achieveable max size (especially with all the reallocations in `push_back`). Then this over-max-size vector is *copied*. Unless your compiler decides to optimize the whole thing away, I'd expect a crash of either your program or your OS.

Comment: what compiler did you use ? All compilers I checked throw an exception for a full vector. I wrote an answer, dont think it is wrong, but it cannot explain what is going on in your code

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm trying to prevent my function from accepting a vector that is too large for the system it is running on. However, now that I think about it, that will happen at compile time because the datatype itself cannot hold more elements than it is allowed to.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen do you know how I can consistently find the max size of a vector for the compiler/OS i'm using?

Comment: You need to enable more compiler warnings - any decent compiler should be able to tell you that `v.size() < 0` can never be true (since every `std::size_t` is at least 0).  On many platforms, `v.max_size()` is equal to the maximum `std::size_t`, making that comparison always true, too.  And why are you printing with `%d` instead of `%zu`?  (Or better, using `<iostream>`?)

Answer (score 0):

Your test completes successfully because you see the following line:

```
[       OK ] FIT_SUM_TEST.TOO_LARGE (46174 ms)
```

There is no simple answer to "when is a vector too large?". In general, you want to pre-allocate memory for a vector if you know its size at compile time.  If you don't do that then the vector will get resized often in a time consuming manner.  Use std::vector::resize() function or specify the size of the vector in the constructor.

In your case however, not preallocating memory in the beginning is what saved your program from crashing.  If you had tried to pre-allocate max_size() elements you would get a bad_alloc exception because an enormous amount of virtual memory is required to achieve this.  push_back() on the other hand will stop allocating additional memory a once available memory is exhausted.  It may or may not through an exception depending on the implementation. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

The reason you see sizes as negative numbers is because you are using an incorrect type specification in printf(). You should be using std::cout instead.